# Creating photo miniature in a List View row

Tags: android

I want to create a list with some text and a photo miniature in each row.
So I created a row layout with a TextView and a ImageView, my question is how do I make the ImageView just a little square and then make an image adapt to the size of the ImageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ImageView .... android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

Set full screen image as an image resource of this image view. It will be downscaled automatically.

Additionally you can limit width and height setting  `android:maxWidth` and `android:maxHeight` attributes to prevent minature to be too large.

Answer (score 0):

my recommendation is you do not scale the image to fit the view as this is an expensive operation and will slow down your app it is preferable to prescale the item to the size you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966). It's a correct way to get miniature with minimum memory consumption.